# How is c (encrypted message) decrypted by private key in RSA?

Tags: algorithm, math, encryption, rsa

I've been studying the concept of RSA algorithm today, And this is what i understood.

## To generate keypair -

- Two prime numbers (p1 = 53, p2 = 59 for example) are multiplied to generate `n` (which will be utilized as the public modulus)
- We use Euler's totient function on our `n` variable and define a new variable `phi`.
- We generate a public exponent `e` in condition that it must be small odd number not sharing factor with our `phi` variable.
- Private key `d` is generated from this formula:

  [image]

  or `d = (k * (phi(n)) + 1) / e`.
- We substitute variables with numbers and get private key:

  [image]

  or `d = (2 * (3016) + 1) /  3 = 2011`

  **We substitute** -
- `k` with `2` (by my knowledge `k` must be more than 0 and less than `phi(n)`)
- `phi(n)` with `3016` (Because `p1 * p2 = 3127` and since the result
  is a prime number, We get its phi easily using `p1` and `p2`. (`phi(n) = (p1-1) * (p2-1)`)
- `e` the exponent with `3` (Because it does not share any factors with 3016 and it's an odd number)

## To use the public key -

Afterwards we can share our `e` and `n` since computers would take decades to get private key from big `n`.

Our communicator encodes message the into the hex and afterwards converts it to base10 integer. Communicator may also add random integer padding for protection.

When message is turned into the number, Modular exponentiation is performed on it:

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

So if message in numbers is 89 for example, If we do modular exponentiation on it we would get:

## 1394

## The Question -

If our communicator sends us `1394` which is encrypted `89` (`89^3 * mod(59 * 53) = 1394`), How do we use our private key to decrypt this message automatically? Is there some specific formula that must be used?

Thank you a lot for reading.

Comment: It's possible that https://crypto.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for your question.

Comment: I get 916 for the encrypted value, not 89. 1394 ^ 3 % 3127.

Comment: @MillieSmith `89^3 * mod(53 * 59)` is `1394`, You must encrypt 89.

Comment: Ah. I interpreted "1394 which is encrypted 89" as "1394 which is encrypted to 89".

Comment: Wikipedia explains the formula. Where's the confusion? http://csharppad.com/gist/0365113b3f58121ed3da4516e1ac5694 (also, your latex formula says `d = 2017` but then in the text right below it says it's 2011.

Comment: Actual variable names: http://csharppad.com/gist/863b96d68853f7b20cd0e72252cb4b11

Comment: @MillieSmith Sorry i wrote it incorrectly, So "d" is only required to know when to break the loop?

Comment: It's the exponent, but of course I can't do `1394 ^ 2011` without a BigInteger class because 64 bits isn't close to enough to hold that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/37483/why-is-rsa-decryption-the-inverse-of-encryption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given: `p = 53`, `q = 59`, `e = 3`.

- `n` = `p * q` = `3127`.
- `phi(n)` = `(p-1) * (q-1)` = `3016`.
- `lambda` = `LCM(p-1, q-1)` = `1508`.
- `dPhi` = `ModInverse(e, phi(n))` = `ModInverse(3, 3016)` = `2011`.
- `dLambda` = `ModInverse(e, lambda)` = `ModInverse(3, 1508)` = `503`.
- And the CRT parameters (which we won't use here)

  - `dp` = `dLambda % (q - 1)` = `503 % 58` = `35`.
  - `dq` = `dLambda % (p - 1)` = `503 % 52` = `39`.
  - `inverseQ` = `ModInverse(q, p)` = `ModInverse(59, 53)` = `9`.

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm were used in the making of `ModInverse`)

Note that `dLambda` is smaller than `dPhi`.  While the original RSA paper used the `phi`-based model, later it was reduced down to the LCM-based model.  Since `(p-1)` and `(q-1)` are both even (since `p` and `q` are primes != `2`) `lambda` ends up being at most `phi / 2`, making for a much smaller modular space for the inverse.

So, assuming we're doing raw/unpadded RSA (because this key is way too small to do padded RSA with):

Given: `m = 89`.

`c` = `m^e % n` = `89^3 % 3127` = `704969 % 3127` = `1394`.

`m` = `c^d % n` = `1394^503 % 3127` = `3.666e1581 % 3127` = ???.

Instead we move on to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation.

`m` = `ModPow(1394, 503, 3127)` => `ModPow(1394, 0b0001_1111_0111, 3127)`:

- R: `1`, base: (1394 % 3127) = `1394`, exponent: `0b0001_1111_0111`
- R: (1 * 1394) % 3127 = `1394`, base: (1394 * 1394) % 3127 = 1943236 % 3127 = `1369`, exponent: `0b0000_1111_1011`
- R: (1394 * 1369) % 3127 = 1908386 % 3127 = `916`, base: (1369 * 1369) % 3127 = 1874161 % 3127 = `1088`, e: `0b0111_1101`
- R: (916 * 1088) % 3127 = 996608 % 3127 = `2222`, base: (1088 * 1088) % 3127 = 1183744 % 3127 = `1738`, e: `0b0011_1110`
- R: `2222`, base: (1738 * 1738) % 3127 = 3020644 % 3127 = `3089`, e: `0b0001_1111`
- R: (2222 * 3089) % 3127 = 6863758 % 3127 = `3120`, base: (3089 * 3089) % 3127 = 9541921 % 3127 = `1444`, e: `0b0000_1111`
- R: (3120 * 1444) % 3127 = 4505280 % 3127 = `2400`, base: (1444 * 1444) % 3127 = 2085136 % 3127 = `2554`, e: `0b0111`
- R: (2400 * 2554) % 3127 = 6129600 % 3127 = `680`, base: (2554 * 2554) % 3127 = 6522916 % 3127 = 3121, e: `0b0011`
- R: (680 * 3121) % 3127 = 2122280 % 3127 = `2174`, base: (3121 * 3121) % 3127 = 9740641 % 3127 = `36`, e: `0b0001`
- R: (2174 * 36) % 3127 = 78264 % 3127 = `89`, base: (36 * 36) % 3127 = 1296 % 3127 = `1296`, e: `0b0000`
- R: `89`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I definitely need to study multiplicative inverse more